# HTML elements not aligned with semantic ui

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

I am trying to simply show a text input field and a button in one line with semantic ui. For some reason the elements are not aligned properly and I can't figure out the css property that is responsible for this:

```
<div id="filter-input" class="ui left icon input">
  <i class="search icon"></i>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui button">Test</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/sonovice/pen/QKYWwN)

**Update:** Corrected closing tag on last div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `float: left;` your input div.

**Just add this lines to your css:**

```
.input {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Or vertical-align your input div:**

```
.input {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Edit:** and you have problem with the HTML syntax. change button open tag:

```
<button class="ui floating button">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The closing tag was a c&p error. I still don't get why this would not work without explicitly letting the input element float?

Comment: You can change your vertical align to middle and its solved your proplem. the next element after the input base on the bottom line. im edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

not this

```
<div class="ui button">Test</button>
```

should be

```
<div class="ui button">Test</div>
```

try put inside the div...

```
<div id="filter-input" class="ui left icon input">
  <i class="search icon"></i>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="ui button">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. But since I would like to place multiple buttons in the line, I prefer the accepted solution. Sorry for that, you were fast like a lightning...